# How to make SplitPane transparent

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to make the SplitPane as thin as possible? I don't want to see the line which divides the panes. But I want to be able to resize the SplitPane with the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the divider's look with CSS.
Check this (very cool) example: [Address Application](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part4/)
and the answer provided on a [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535397/javafx-hide-slider-divider-of-the-splitpane)

Comment: the '.split-pane-divider' selector of the linked tutorial helped me a lot styling my SplitPane separator, thanks!